# is it possible to set image size while taking screenshot of uiview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

in my app i am taking screenshot of uiview. but i want to set that image size. like size of uiview is 100*100 and i want to take that screenshot and set the image size to 50*50 so how can it possible?

here  is my code:

```
 func screenshot(vieww : UIView)-> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(vieww.frame.size, vieww.isOpaque, 0.0)
    vieww.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's possible please try this

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));
in place of 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(vieww.frame.size, vieww.isOpaque, 0.0)

Please let me know if it's work

Thank you